# Issues installing "quanteda" in R

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda

I am trying to install quanteda package for text-mining in R (ver. 3.2.2.) running on Ubuntu 15.10.
The message I receive is the old classic:

```
  `Warning in install.packages :
   package ‘quanteda’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)`
```

Yet, I have tried with dependencies

```
   install.packages("quanteda", dependencies = T)
```

and suggestions from github

```
   devtools::install_github("kbenoit/quanteda", ref = "03ae172")
```

without any result.

Any workaround?

Comment: The solution is to use a newer version of R. From `DESCRIPTION`, you can see that the version of *quanteda* on CRAN has: `Depends: R (≥ 3.4.0), methods`.

Answer (score 0):

As Ken Benoit noted in his comment, quanteda requires R 3.40 or newer. If you're going to upgrade your R release, you should also upgrade Ubuntu to a newer version. Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily Werewolf) reached its end of life on July 28, 2016. Details about support dates for Ubuntu releases are on the [Ubuntu Releases web page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Instructions on how to install R on Ubuntu Xenial (supported through April 2021) are available via Kris Eberwein's [R-bloggers article on this topic](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-on-linux-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/).